# failing to add values in a linked list in C

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I have a linked list of character arrays:

```
typedef struct node {
    char * line;
    struct node* next;
} node;
typedef struct linked_list {
    node* head;
} list;
```

An add function, i.e.:

```
void add(list* my_list, char * current_line) {
    node* new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new_node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    new_node->line = current_line;
    new_node->next = my_list->head;
    my_list->head = new_node;
    printf(">>> %s", new_node->line);
}
```

I read files by line:

```
while ((getline(&buffer, &size_of_buffer, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("%s", buffer);
        add(my_list, buffer);
        printf("-->%s", my_list->head->line);
```

However, I cannot traverse the list:

```
void traverse_list(list* my_list) {
    if(my_list == NULL || my_list->head == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Nothing to traverse!\n");
    }
    for(node* cursor = my_list->head; cursor; cursor = cursor->next) {
        printf("%s", cursor->line);
    }

}
```

The last function only gives me the last line. In stead I want to see all lines.

Comment: I cannot spot any obvious mistake. You should provide a [mcve]. In the example create the list with fixed data, not from a file.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana The problem is in reading data from a file.

Comment: you  use one `buffer` location for all input strings ... you need to allocate memory for each string to keep it in your program !!

Comment: Yup, specifically here: 'new_node->line = current_line;' just loads a pointer to tbe same buffer every time, so all nodes end up pointing to the same buffer with the last entry:(

Comment: Still not solving the issue: